# Storing database id

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I wonder where to put the database id in the activity for retrieval later at a button click or e.g.

The case is I got a ListView with data. User clicks on a listitem and gets to another activity which presentes the details for that item.

In this detail activity I have delete and update actions. For the delete I ofcourse need the database id.

Sure, I can put it in hidden textview but that seems kind of off as I don't wanna mix userinterface with logic or is this the right approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: store in shared pref

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTag` for list items, or share your collection to other objects by `static`